# How to test the verilog module generated by Chisel in VCS ? How does vpi_uer.cc work in chisel?

Tags: chisel

In chisel-tutorial ,after I ran

```
sbt "run Hello --backend v --compile --test --genHarness --vcd"
```

I got the Hello.v ,Hello-harness.v ,vpi_user.cc files

- How can I test the Hello.v file?
- What is the usage of vpi_user.cc?

Answer (score 0):

To test your design in VCS you can use the two verilog files generated:

- Hello.v : Your Chisel design generated in Verilog
- Hello-harness.v : Your testbench code in Verilog (generated by --genHarness option). Of course you have to modify it to improve your test.