# How to generate harness in Chisel3

Tags: chisel

In Chisel2 there's seems to be a way to generate harness judging by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31444699/how-to-test-the-verilog-module-generated-by-chisel-in-vcs-how-does-vpi-uer-cc).

It seems that the simulation mechanism is a bit different between Chisel2 and Chisel3. Quoted from the [Chisel3 wiki](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/wiki/Chisel3-vs-Chisel2):

> Chisel2 was capable of directly generating a C++ simulation from the Chisel code, or a harness for use with a vcs simulation. Chisel3 relies on verilator to generate the C++ simulation from the Verilog output of firrtl. See the Chisel3 README for directions on installing verilator.

My question is: Is there a way in Chisel3 to generate verilog harness, similar to Chisel2?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might take a look at 
src/main/scala/dsptools/tester/VerilogTbDump.scala
in the [dsptools project](https://github.com/ucb-bar/dsptools).  The tb stands for test-bench. You may be able to find some clues on getting started.  Or hopefully someone else will come along with a better answer.